# Address misspelt in passport/ problems with US F1 visa

Tags: usa, passports, india, study, f1-visas

I am an incoming graduate student to the US and I will shortly apply for the F1 visa. While requesting for the I20 I filled up my current address wherein I stated 'Apartment' in the address column. However, in my passport, it says 'Appt.'. I have gotten my I20 with this address, but I still need to provide the address for different other forms like SEVIS fee payment. Should I proceed with this or change the spelling?

Comment: That's an abbreviation, not a spelling mistake. Why would it cause a problem? Many (most?) countries' passports don't have your address in them anyway. I've lived at three different addresses in the last ten years and it would be really annoying to have to get a new passport everytime I moved.

Comment: There is a type in 'Appt.' which is why I was worried.

Comment: Oh. You're right. I hadn't even noticed, and probably nor did [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/137444/11491). This kind of trivial error really shouldn't affect your application. As I said, most passports don't include an address anyway, and somebody misspelling "Apt." hardly makes you a danger to the USA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the word "apartment" is spelled out or abbreviated is entirely unimportant.  You can use whichever spelling you prefer.